# .htaccess RewriteEngine on breaks CGI Application

Tags: .htaccess, cgi

My .htaccess file is in the root directory of my website, and I narrowed down a problem to the single line of code `RewriteEngine on`. How do I know it's this piece of code? Because I deleted the entire `.htaccess` file except for `RewriteEngine on` as a test... and my CGI application still broke.

If anyone has any idea why the `RewriteEngine on` line decides to break the CGI application all on its own I'd love to hear it!

PS - Just in case you're interested, the piece of code that I want to get working is to help consolidate all domains into a single domain (the line breaks are there simply to make it easier to read):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.html 
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Chances are that [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is not currently enabled in your Apache configuration (usually in httpd.conf).

If it is enabled, it would look something like this:

```
# For Unix-like OSes
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

or

```
# For Windows
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.dll
```

as well as

```
# For both
AddModule mod_rewrite.c
```

The `AddModule` line may not be necessary in Apache 2.0/2.2.

Some OSes place Apache module loaders in another directory.  On Debian and Ubuntu Linuxes, configuration files for installed modules are in /etc/apache2/modules-available, and can be activated with `a2enmod modulename`; in this case `a2enmod rewrite`.